# Magento2.2 links not working after migration of site

Tags: magento2.2

I have a magento 2.2. based website I had setup on a hosting account that used domain http://development.domain.com . I now moved the mysql and the files over to what will be the production hosting account so the site is now located at http://www.domain.com/v2
After I moved the files and database I then via mysql workbench edited the core_config_data table making the web/unsecure/base_url and the web/secure/base_url . columns have www.domain.com/v2/ .

However now when I go to http://www.domain.com/v2 the main magento page loads however if I click any category or product it redirects me to www.domain.com/ .  So like if I click a category named shirts I am being directed to http://www.domain.com/shirts instead of https://www.domain.com/v2/shirts

I also am not able to access the admin panel it just redirects to the url without the /v2/    I checked .htaccess doesnt have any rewrite rules.

I also re-indexed on the cli and compiled and cleared cache. still no change? 
So what am I miising to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its resolved by this query.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `store_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

After this login to ssh and run below query step by setp.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Thanks